# My EditText's setText didn't have compiler error, but the app force closed

Tags: java, android, android-textinputedittext

I want to make my EditText get something from my firebase database, but it can't do setText method
I read many things from stackoverflow, but can't get the problem of my app

Here is the class code:

```
public class TabFragment4 extends Fragment {
Uri filePath;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@Nullable LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment4_layout, container, false);
    Bundle b1 = this.getArguments();
    final String name = b1.getString("name");
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("user").child(name);
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String na = dataSnapshot.child("nama").getValue(String.class);
            String ma = dataSnapshot.child("hp").getValue().toString();
            EditText edit1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
            EditText edit2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit2);
            edit1.setText(na);
            edit2.setText("Test");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
    Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btng1);

    ImageView ipv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivp);
    new DownloadImageTask(ipv)
            .execute("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tugasakhir-6571b.appspot.com/o/images%2F"+name+"?alt=media");
    ipv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, PICK_IMAGE);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    ImageView imgProf = (ImageView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.ivp);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
        filePath = data.getData();
        imgProf.setImageURI(filePath);
    }
}
```

}

I can't do setText with String variable, even with new String directly

Comment: can you share the error that is printed in the log

Comment: Is this code a part of a `Fragment`? Please post the whole class.

Comment: Please post you crash report

Comment: I can't see the crash report because my USB port is error and my laptop can't effort to open emulator and android studio at same time

Yes, my code is a part of Fragment, i'll edit the post with my full class

Comment: No, it isn't
I can't even write the String directly

Comment: I use Fragment4.this.getView().findViewById and still can't get it